# Daylight saving issues with get date function

Tags: javascript, function, date, utc

I am having issues with day light savings, I have tried tons of diferent ways but not working. Our clients are global so I did not want to use any timezone stuff.

The idea is you give a date and amount of days and get back a date. the date input has to be "DD-MM-YYYY" as we get this from an other system.

this is the code

```
CallculateDateFromDays = function(startDate, days) {
    var policy_start_date_array = startDate.split("-");
    var policy_start_date = new Date(policy_start_date_array[2], policy_start_date_array[1]-1, policy_start_date_array[0]);
    var epoch = Math.floor(policy_start_date.getTime()/1000);
    var days_seconds = (days - 1) * 86400;
    var total_seconds = epoch + days_seconds;
    var end_date = new Date(total_seconds*1000);
    var dateString = ("0" + (end_date.getDate())).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (end_date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + end_date.getFullYear();
    alert(dateString + " " + epoch);
};
CallculateDateFromDays("27-10-2013",2);
```

this should return the 28-10-2013 but when I use the date "27-10-2013" it returns "27-10-2013", but any other date is fine. I have tried using UTC but still same result.

Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/89jmU/

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/89jmU/3/ but did you really mean `days - 1`?

Comment: Thank you so much, was pulling my hair out, yes we minus the day as we count today as the first day of purchase of a car insurance policy